# How to get html form ckeditor5?

Tags: ckeditor5

I want to get the content written by Editer5 and submit it to save，but only text information can be obtained, and the content of the picture can not be obtained.
[this is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvCSL.png)

[this is my editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7gL7.png)

[this is my edit content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/to5O1.png)

[in editor html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHkEP.png)

[but  has no data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwlp3.png)

Answer (score 1):

You assign created editor instance to a variable and then use the [getData function](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_core_editor_utils_dataapimixin-DataApi.html#function-getData). You can use `.then` on editor creation and assign it there:

```
var myEditor;

ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
    .then( editor => {
        console.log( 'Editor was initialized', editor );
        myEditor = editor;
    } )
    .catch( err => {
        console.error( err.stack );
    } );
```

and then get data using  `myEditor.getData();`

Please also have a look at: https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/ui/document-editor.html#the-editor

Comment: but it doesn't return actual html, getData() returns the text